# How do I prevent the element of an HTML5 form from moving slightly?

Tags: css, html

I added a ":focus" CSS property to my input elements where it will add a solid border to each text input if it's clicked on.

Here's a Jsfiddle to the form, click on any text input and you'll notice a slight movement

```
<form>
<h1>Send me a Message</h1>
<label for="name">Name</label><br>
<input type="text" id="name" class="inpt-styles"><br>
<label for="email">Email</label><br>
<input type="text" id="email" class="inpt-styles"><br>
<label for="message">Message</label><br>
<textarea row="5" col"8" id="message" class="inpt-styles txtarea"></textarea><br>
<button type="submit">Send</button>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ug40ku9v/1/)

How can I prevent this movement from happening and make the form feel more solid?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options:

- add a transparent border on the non-focused input. This way the size won't change on focus, and you won't get the moving effect.
- work with `outline` in stead of `border`. Outlines do not take up space and therefore won't move the form either. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline

Answer (score 0):

Set a border on the input elements to begin with but make it transparent, like this:
`border: 1px solid transparent`